# Use of the term 'Milk kinship'

Tags: word-usage

This was an Arab custom that they would send their young kids for nursing. The women who would breastfeed the kids would have a relation called 'Milk kinship'. In some of the articles, I've read a word 'milk-brother' for the two kids, one who is biologically the son of the woman who breastfed the other who's not biologically her kids. Is it a right use?

milk-son

milk-mother

milk- brother

milk-sib

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the general term for it is

> [milk sibling](https://www.yourdictionary.com/milk-sibling) - *A person who is not one's biological sibling but was nursed by the same woman as oneself (e.g., the child of one's wet nurse).*

The page also mentions the ritual or tradition in Islamic law.

I agree that [*milk brother/sister*](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Milk_brother) is also a term in use; furthermore, milk-mother or wet nurse is also the term used in the same context.